# Phonegap - Sqlite Questions

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I use: cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.3 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin" in my Phonegap App for Android.

And I have some questions.

```
db.transaction(
function(tx){

            // 1 QUERY - Empty Set
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table1', [],
                // Success Callback
                function(transaction, result) {

                },
                // Error Callback
                function(error){

                }
            );

            // 2 QUERY - Insert 10 records in my table
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO table1 (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)', ['id' + i, 'data' + i],
                    // Success Callback
                    function(transaction, result) {

                    },
                    // Error Callback
                    function(error){

                    }
                );
            }

            // 3 QUERY - 10 rows in Set
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table1', [],
                // Success Callback
                function(transaction, result) {

                },
                // Error Callback
                function(error){

                }
            );

        },
        // Error callback
        function(error){

        },
        // Success callback
        function(){

        }
    );
```

I have 12 queries in my transaction.

1 QUERY - Empty Set

2 QUERY - Insert 10 records in my table

3 QUERY - 10 rows in Set

**1. Will my 12 queries executed consistently ?**

1 query -> 10 insert queries in loop -> 3 query

**2. If i'll get error in second step in my loop, or may be i add 13 insert query at the end and get error in 13 query. Will all my changes inside transaction ROLLBACK ?**

**3. Whats happened if my db transaction will be in progress and i push HOME button and hide application ? Will my transaction finished in background ? Or may be it's stopped ?**

Thank's for advance!

Comment: Why don't you test and see what happens?

Comment: I tested sequence of queries! It's OK. But i am not sure that it will be ok all time with more difficult queries.